# Flutter model with optional list now gives errors after move to null aware

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a model that has included a list that can have zero to many entries. Now I've moved to null aware, I get an error stating that "The default value of an optional parameter must be constant".

How can I create a list that can have zero entries?

```
class Aaa{
  String name;
  String unit;
  List<Bbb> bbb;
  Aaa({
     this.name='',
     this.unit='',
     this.bbb=[],
  });
}
class Bbb{
  DateTime theTime;
  int amount;
  Bbb({
    required this.theTime,
    required this.amount,
  });
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `const` keyword to the initializer of `bbb`.

```
class Aaa{
  String name;
  String unit;
  List<Bbb> bbb;
  Aaa({
     this.name='',
     this.unit='',
     this.bbb= const [],
  });
```

As the error states: **The default value of an optional parameter must be constant".**

Also, this error is not related to the *null safety* feature. It is a requirement of dart classes that default params should be initialized with a `const` value.

However, If you want to initialize `Aaa` with a `null` value for `bbb` then you should update the `bbb` field to have a `?` at the end, this tells the compiler that this value maybe null, like so

```
class Aaa{
...
List<Bbb>? bbb;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<dynamic>bbb;
```

Or

```
List bbb;
```

You must set your list type to dynamic or int, if you know that the data coming is only int